# lazyload in not loading images on the new page while using infinite scroll

Tags: php, smarty, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

I am using 
Paul Irish's infinite scroll 
http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html
and Mike Tupupola's lazy load jquery script to load images on the page.

Images are loading perfectly fine for the first page. However as soon as the infinite scroll kicks in at the end of the page and loads new elements. It loads everything except the images. which means that the lazyload jquery is not kicking in for the newly loaded elements.

link of the page : http://67.20.122.201/boikeno/viewmore.php?view=popular

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided does not work.